# Why do I keep seeing Umbraco.Web.PublishedModels and Umbraco.Web.Models?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

I am new to Umbraco, can anyone tell me why I am seeing these 2 values instead of the expected string?

I get Umbraco.Web.Models when I use this code to get a link

var businessLink = child.Value("websiteLink");

And Umbraco.Web.PublishedModels when trying to use this code to get the name of the previous child to my current node:

var business = child.AncestorsOrSelf("Business").Last();

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to show more of your code.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but for Umbraco v8, all of the following extension methods are available on `Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent` so you can have strongly typed access to all of them with intellisense for both content and media. These methods return `IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>`.

```
Children() // this is the same as using the Children property on the content item.
Ancestors()
Ancestors(int level)
Ancestors(string nodeTypeAlias)
AncestorsOrSelf()
AncestorsOrSelf(int level)
AncestorsOrSelf(string nodeTypeAlias)
Descendants()
Descendants(int level)
Descendants(string nodeTypeAlias)
DescendantsOrSelf()
DescendantsOrSelf(int level)
DescendantsOrSelf(string nodeTypeAlias)
Siblings()
SiblingsAndSelf()
```

Alternatively, you have other methods that return a single `IPublishedContent`.

```
Ancestor()
AncestorOrSelf()
AncestorOrSelf(int level)
AncestorOrSelf(string nodeTypeAlias)
AncestorOrSelf(Func<IPublishedContent, bool> func)
```

More information can be found here: https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/querying

Comment: My issue is when I call the variable in my html it prints 'Umbraco.Web.PublishedModels' instead of a value, do you know why this is the case?

Comment: Looks like you are missing some basic steps in your implementation. You can check this git repo which I created after following Paul Seal's Umbraco v8 videos on his YouTube channel. Also, take a look at the Umbraco documentation for v8 to make sure you are not missing anything.

https://github.com/NurhakKaya/CleanBlog.Web

https://www.youtube.com/@CodeSharePaul/videos

https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Fundamentals/Design/Rendering-Content/

Comment: Thank you I have managed to get it working now.

Comment: Great news, please remember to share your fix here, and also upvote/accept answers that help you.